# Null is being shown when list containing data from database is displayed

Tags: java, list

I'am new to java, this question may have been asked earlier but I'm not getting the exact answer.I want to add data from database into at and display it through jsp. But empty or null values is shown i.e no data is being displayed and when I execute the same sql query which is used in code in sql server ,then required output is displayed.
My java code is:

```js
public List < Alarm_Bean > get_Count(String system_Name)

{

  if (system_Name.equals("MPS"))

  {
    try {
      con = getConnection();

      stmt = con.createStatement();

      String sql = " select system_name,COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c from i2alarmlog where Ack_status=0 AND Direction='CAME' and system_name in( 'I2-tciu database','i2-mps database') group by system_name union all select 'sum' system_name, Count(distinct arrival_time) from i2alarmlog where Ack_status=0 AND Direction='CAME' and system_name in( 'I2-tciu database','i2-mps database')   ";

      stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      rs = stmt.getResultSet();



      while (rs.next()) {
        Alarm_Bean obj = new Alarm_Bean();


        obj.setSystem_name(rs.getString("system_name"));

        obj.setC(rs.getString("c"));
        at.add(obj);
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("\nException " + e);
    } finally {
      closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
    }
  }
  //System.out.println(at);

  return at;

}
```

Jsp code is:-

```
<c:out value="${ab.get_Count(MPS)}"></c:out>
```

Comment: @xavy at is list ,    private List<Alarm_Bean> at= new ArrayList<Alarm_Bean>();

Comment: have you tried to print out the value you get ? `System.out.println(obj.getSystem_name());` inside the loop

Comment: yes ,its showing null,but it can't be null,as in another method i have used obj.getSystem_name() and correct output is displayed.