# sql query to sum the total count

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have to calculate the sum of total count value for each distinct arrival_time (column in database table) corresponding to column system_name. My sql query is:

```
SELECT   system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c 
FROM     i2alarmlog 
WHERE    Ack_status = 0 
AND      Direction='CAME' 
AND      system_name in('I2-tciu database',
                        'i2-vcs logging',
                        'Indus1 Vacuum',
                        'Indus2 TCIU',
                        'Indus2 Vacuum',
                        'Septum_SIP2',
                        'TL3 Vacuum') 
GROUP BY system_name 

UNION ALL

SELECT   'sum' system_name,
          Count(distinct arrival_time) 
FROM     i2alarmlog 
WHERE    Ack_status=0 
AND      Direction='CAME'
AND      system_name in( 'I2-tciu database'
                        ,'i2-vcs logging',
                         'Indus1 Vacuum',
                         'Indus2 Vacuum',
                         'Septum_SIP2',
                         'TL3 Vacuum')
```

When I run this sql query then sum is shown as 1841 but actually its 1845.

```
i2-vcs logging      2
I2-tciu database    2
Indus1 Vacuum       19
Indus2 TCIU         120
Indus2 Vacuum       1691
Septum_SIP2         8
TL3 Vacuum          3
sum                 1841
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query, the `distinct` part is applied to all data. That means, if you have the same `arrival time` for 2 different products, it will only be counted once, and not once for each product. That would explain the difference between your expected and actual results.

What you could do instead is this:

```
;with cte as
(SELECT   system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c 
 FROM     i2alarmlog 
 WHERE    Ack_status = 0 
 AND      Direction='CAME' 
 AND      system_name in('I2-tciu database','i2-vcs logging','Indus1 Vacuum','Indus2 TCIU','Indus2 Vacuum','Septum_SIP2','TL3 Vacuum') 
 GROUP BY system_name )

select system_name, c
from cte
union
select 'sum', sum(c) as c
from cte
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JRANKR77314)

Comment: thanks..I have one more doubt  i.e how to store the obtained output in a list and display it through jsp. As when I do this,then null is being displayed.

Comment: Please create a separate question to get help with this issue. You may link this question for context. Thanks!

Comment: I already have at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416457/null-is-being-shown-when-list-containing-data-from-database-is-displayed.but no help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is by using an inline view and calculate the total sum like so:

```
SELECT   system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c 
FROM     i2alarmlog 
WHERE    Ack_status = 0 
AND      Direction='CAME' 
AND      system_name in('I2-tciu database','i2-vcs logging','Indus1 Vacuum','Indus2 TCIU','Indus2 Vacuum','Septum_SIP2','TL3 Vacuum') 
GROUP BY system_name 

UNION ALL

select 'TotalSum' as TotalSum, sum(s.c) as TotalValue
from
(
    SELECT   system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c 
    FROM     i2alarmlog 
    WHERE    Ack_status = 0 
    AND      Direction='CAME' 
    AND      system_name in('I2-tciu database','i2-vcs logging','Indus1 Vacuum','Indus2 TCIU','Indus2 Vacuum','Septum_SIP2','TL3 Vacuum') 
    GROUP BY system_name 
) s
```

With this solution the maximum agregation level (2) was reached ( sum(count(value)) ).

Comment: it worked...can you tell me how to store the obtained output in a list and dispaly it through jsp.As when I do this,then null is being dispalyed.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA, I don't have any knowledge on jsp related but you can try this: select * from (<add here all the above code with the 2 queries>) as a